# Solve equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

`a` is older than `b`. Taking present ages of `a` and `b` as `x` years and `y` years respectively, find in terms of `x` and `y`:

1. The difference between the ages of `a` and `b`
2. The age of `b` when `a` was of `y` years.

If the age of `b` obtained in step 2 , is half the present age of `a` and the sum of the present ages of `a` and `b` Is 42 years, find the present age of `a` and `b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x-y$ is there age difference, and it will always remain. If $a$ is $y$ years old at one point in time than $b$ is still "$x-y$" years younger:

$$y-(x-y)=2y-x$$

But that is half the present age of $a$ which is $x$, thus doubling it will give you $x$.

$$2(2y-x)=4y-2x=x$$

Or this means:

$$4y-3x=0$$

The other equation is given, and obvious:

$$y+x=42$$

Can you do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

1. $x-y$
2. $y-(x-y) = 2y-x$

Then we get the equations:

$2y-x = x/2$

$x+y = 42$

If we rearrange this, we get the linear equation system with two equations:

$-3x/2 + 2y = 0$

$x+y = 42$

or in matrix form:

$${\bf Ax = b} , \text{, where } {\bf A} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\-1.5&2\end{array}\right], {\bf b} = \left[\begin{array}{c}42\\0\end{array}\right]$$
which has the solution ${\bf x} = \left[\begin{array}{c}24\\18\end{array}\right]$ which corresponds to current age of a (x) being 24 and current age of b (y) being 18.

Now it will be an easy exercise plugging in the numbers $x$ and $y$ into the expressions at 1. and 2. above.